# How to fully deactivate Apple App Clip - it still pops up

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc, apple-appclips

I added Apple App Clip but later removed it not yet needed. It was added "Advanced App Clip Experience", later deactivated, but when you bring the NFC tag to the phone, an alert still pops up with an empty content and message "This app clip is not currently available in your country or region".
[image]

1. Deactivated Advanced app clip in App Store Connect
   [image]
2. Expired all builds in TestFlight, which contain App Clips
   [image]
3. Everything in app association file, domains for app clips, etc - removed
   [image]
   So why NFC scanning still present App Clip, but not redirect me in app/safari as earlier?

Comment: This sounds like a caching issue to me. Either the local cache on the device for the AASA file needs to be invalidated by iOS or Apple's web crawler system cache is not picking up your change yet. I'd try it with a different device and see what happens.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  The fix was to ensure that the App Clip Experience was deactivated in App Store Connect.

- I submitted a binary/build that contained an App Clip to Testflight so that I could access the Advance App Clip settings.
- Deactivated the App Clip Experience (your step #1)
- Waited a day to account for the caching system, and now, after testing, scanning my QR Code (in your case, it would be triggering the event with the NFC tag) produces the correct results.

It is important to note that even though you may have a live app that does not contain an App Clip, you must still deactivate it in Advance App Clip.